# How to stream desktop through audio jack (3.5) using dsp

Tags: linux, audio, streaming, pcm

Is it possible to stream my desktop over audio system? I mean some kind of `cat /dev/fb0 > /dev/dsp`?

Or to pulse-code my desktop using built-in soundcard and to stream it over optical spdif audio-out port,  where on the other end its raw data could be then recoded into image with kind of sstv algorythm?

I`m interesting both on possibility of such action and existing software (m.b. pulseaudio could?)

UPD: if assume that the channel`s on 100 Mhz FM data capacity is around 100 kbit/s and rdp protocol on 1024x768 with 256 colors eats around 40 kbit/s (am I wrong?) than it is really enough to stream rdp over audiochannel. And if spdif is used than there will be no digital-to-analog-to-digital transition even. So I wonder how it could be set to input from spdif on other end (for example, my Gateway NV57 laptop has line-out 3.5 jack with built-in SPDiF, I should just to capture on it after connected the wire from source PC - ?).

Comment: While this might be theoretically possible, the bandwidth would be horrible and the lag due to processing time would make it hardly a "stream".

Comment: Tony Hoare http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare (inventor of Quicksort),  who ran the Programming Research Group in the Oxford, in the 1970's used audio speakers to monitor hard disk activity; and I think all the rest of us still use our ears from time-to-time.

Comment: Just another "proof of concept" that it can be done, you can get [credit card readers](https://squareup.com/) for your phone that use DSP to talk to a peripheral over the headphone port.

Comment: However on the flip side your audio jack is not a FM transmitter and can do nowhere near the 100MHz of a FM carrier wave, most audio sytems run at 44.1 KHz, so you may want to redo your math.

Comment: Yes, Scott, I know it. The way of transmitting the signal through space - is the next question, the first is to be sure it could be produced.

Comment: Well, I think I am close to open the consept of packet radio ))

Answer (score 0):

What you are basically looking for is a [softmodem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmodem).

From some basic googling there is not too much out there for linux, but I did find [this project](http://bellard.org/linmodem.html) which under its description it says it has a soundcard interface it supports.

Another option, if both computers have open serial/parralel ports is to use a [null modem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_modem) cable to network them. That has a [lot better support](https://www.google.com/search?q=null%20modem%20linux) in linux.